# Is there a "show cdp neighbors" type command for Cisco ASA devices?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, networking, cdp

I have been working on a project to map out my organization's network infrastructure.  For the networking devices (we are a Cisco shop) I have been running the `show cdp neighbors` command to see how everything is connected and through which interface.  I am noticing that our ASA is not showing up in the output of these commands (it is connected to a Cisco switch).  I ran a command list via `show ?` and CDP does not show up as an option.

My question is this: is there a command similar to `show cdp neighbors` that will show to which devices the ASA is connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASA's do not support CDP.  About the best you can do is to look at the MAC address of the interface and then look through the switch mac-address or CAM tables.